# Why does my ArrayList only print out the last subclass that was called?

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, polymorphism

I'm currently learning polymorphism in Java, and part of the assignment was to create a program that will print out various subclasses using inheritance and polymorphism. I have tried looking for solutions but I couldn't seem to find anyone else experiencing this issue.

Below is a piece of code that is supposed to print `Alex` and `Alexa` respectively. However, the output is, instead, `Alexa` `Alexa`.

I have tried debugging by stepping through using Eclipse, but I can't pinpoint what is the mistake. I am truly stumped at this point, I've been trying this question for the past week but to no avail. Please forgive me if this is a simple question but I can't figure out what went wrong. I would truly appreciate any assistance!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Human {
   protected static String name;

   public Human(String name) {
       System.out.println("In human constructor");
       this.name = name;
   }
   void greetings() {}

   static void print(Human human) {
       System.out.println(name);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       ArrayList<Human> human = new ArrayList<Human>();
       human.add(new Man("Alex"));
       human.add(new Woman("Alexa"));
       for (int i = 0; i < human.size(); i++) {
           print(human.get(i));
       }
   }
}

class Man extends Human {

   public Man(String name) {
       super(name);
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }

}

class Woman extends Human {

   public Woman(String name) {
       super(name);
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }

}
```

Comment: remove the static from protected static String name;

Comment: A `static` variable doesn't belong to a specific instance; rather it is common for all the instances. That is why you whenever its value is changed, it will be changed for all the instances.

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things wrong here:

1. `name` should not be static. You want an instance of `name` for each instance (object) created.
2. You are printing the wrong `name`. You want to print the `name` of the instance passed into `print()`. So you would want something like this (you would create a getter method for `name`):

```
static void print(Human human) {
    System.out.println(human.getName());
}
```

Comment: Why would you pass a `Human` to itself to print itself?  Why wouldn't you just do `void print() { System.out.println(this.name) }` and call it with `yourHuman.print()`?  The way you have it now it is not `static` so you would be requiring an instance of `Human` to print a _different_ `Human` which makes no sense.  Either have it `static` with a `Human` parameter, or make it not `static` with no parameter

Comment: @Nexevis you are correct

Answer (score 1):

Do some research on the static context. Here is part of your problem:

```
protected static String name;
```

Making `name` static means that it belongs to the `Human` class. That means every object of class `Human` will have the same name.

If you want `Human` objects to have different names, remove that `static` modifier.

Next, `Human` should probably be a POJO, instead of your main class. Something like this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human human = new Human("Steve");

        System.out.println(human.getName());
    }
}

class Human {
    private String name;

    Human(String s) {
        this.name = s;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only fix part of the problem...

Comment: you are mistaken, it will not print the correct names. Try it...

Comment: `name` will be `null`...

Comment: @brso05 whoops, I thought `Human` was a POJO but it contains the `main` - I stand corrected.

Answer (score 1):

every Human has his own name, no matter if Man or Woman.

so remove the static keyword from

```
protected static String name;
```

Comment: This will only fix part of the problem...

Answer (score 1):

This is because you've defined `name` as a static field. so in every object it will have the same value. just remove the `static` from name.

```
protected String name;
```

when a variable, method, ... is defined `static`, you can have access to it without creating objects. meanwhile it will have the same value in each object. so if you are modifying a static variable, it will keep the last modification.

take a look at [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-keyword-java/) for more information.

Comment: This will only fix part of the problem...